# new ubuntu install on an IBM T 42 Thinkpad

Tags: installation, thinkpad

I have tried installing 3 or 4 versions of ubuntu from my flash drive but am unsuccessful.  Is there anyone who has a step by step guide as to how this is done and what version?  I kept going back version by version due to a CPA error for the processor, I look around online for others who have done this and mostly I find statements that Ubuntu works great on their T 42 but no explanation as to how that was accomplished.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My T 42 has XP and I would like to try running Ubuntu from a stick or installed along with XP before I commit completely to the Linux OS..  Thanks so much!! - John

Answer (score 0):

You can use your flash drive to boot from it, without having to install anything, and feel if Ubuntu is right for you or not.

If you, then, decide to give it a go, there's a lot of tutorials. However, I'd recommend you to watch a couple of videos on YouTube, just to check your steps. Maybe you're just missing some small step.

I'm not leaving any link because I'm not the author, nor responsible for their content.